# Issues with Infinite Mana Loop and Grindclock/ Clock of Omens Combo

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an idea for an Instant mil combo involving the below cards:

1. [Grindclock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grindclock)
2. [Clock of Omens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clock%20of%20Omens)
3. [Palladium Myr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Palladium%20Myr) x2
4. [Myr Galvanizer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Myr%20Galvanizer) x2
5. [Darksteel Forge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Forge) (just so they cant be destroyed, always helpful)

I'm wondering how I would have to order my tapping to allow me to build up 60+ counters on Grindclock, to then mil for 60+ cards.

I know I'd need to tap Palladium Myr and Grindclock first, but then it gets slightly difficult. Can anyone provide me with the Order in which I would have to tap these permanents to create the infinite mil and manna Loop in kind?

Comment: @diego How do I Hyperlink the card names quickly because I heard theres a simpler way than using the hyperlink option?

Comment: If you do [mtg:Card Name] it will automatically link to the Gatherer page for that card (there are some edge cases it doesn't work and you will have to manually link cards, but it works most of the time)

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to get up to 60 counters. You could just get up to 8 counters and mill 8 times. I know you're going for the infinite, but the non-infinite cases, keep it in mind.

Comment: @jonthemon yeah I guess it's six and two threes to be honest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Tap Grindclock
2. Tap both Palladium to float 4x colorless
3. Spend colorless to activate Galvanizer and untap Palladiums
4. Tap both Palladium to untap Grindclock (clock of omens)
5. Tap Grindclock
6. Spend colorless to activate Galvanizer and untap Palladiums and Galvanizer
7. Tap both Palladium to float 4x colorless
8. Spend colorless to activate Galvanizer and untap Palladiums and Galvanizer
9. Goto step 4.